# "You cannot send more than 5 messages in 1 hour"

Tags: emails

I have several contact forms, but I don't want to limit the users to submit the form. I've tried form unblock with smart IP; it doesn't work for me.

Do you have any idea to release the IP and unset the limit?

Comment: See core/modules/contact/config/install/contact.settings.yml

Comment: can i just change this value to take effect?

Comment: and where is the flood table in db?

Answer (score 6):

Change it using drush config-set.

To get the default settings use:

```
drush config-get contact.settings
```

To change the limit to 100 instead of 5, use:

```
drush config-set contact.settings flood.limit 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The flood setting is a configuration value, but it isn't exposed in the administration interface, so you can't easily change it in the site. Changing the `config/install/contact.settings.yml` file will not work (unless you then reinstall the module), and editing core files is always a bad idea. But you can set configuration values using the drush or [drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/) command-line tools, eg. `drupal config:edit contact.settings`.

Comment: Importing updated settings here: /admin/config/development/configuration/full/import for a single item "contact.settings" with updated values like so worked fine for me!    flood:
  limit: 20
  interval: 3600